# Self-answered questions about basic concepts

Tags: discussion

Today I encountered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24261050/) and I'm unsure to make of it.

It seems like the core problem is:

> Q:"Why can't I find the declaration of `X` in class `bar`?"
>
> A:"Because `X` is declared in `foo` which `bar` extends."

This is a basic principle of OO programming, but it's complicated by the way [flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flex) structures its classes. I'm in two minds about this question:

1. I can understand that this specific feature might be difficult to find
2. The method of finding it is so basic, it seems to fall into the "fails to demonstrate basic understanding" off topic clause.

Obviously I can down vote if I decide its bad, but should I do more? What would the community recommend when encountering questions like this?

Comment: Note that there were ~8 minutes between the question and the answer, so it might have been a successful rubberducking, and the user thought it might help someone if he left the solution he found on his own.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: or ... err bad internet connection, or just some newcomer feeling how to do it quicker. :)

Comment: Also notice that the answer (self answer) have 2 upvotes as well which means that someone found that useful or worth to be +1 for.

Comment: @FinalContest: The "answer your own question" feature always leaves the same timestamp

Comment: @PlasmaHH: I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: @FinalContest: "bad internet connection" seems to refer to the reason of the 8 minutes difference to be the time it was needed to post an answer. The "self-answered question" in this questions title seems to refer to the "answer your own question" feauter, which posts both, the answer and the question at the same time. As such the 8 minute gap is a strong indicator that this feature was not used.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: I think you do not get what I am trying to say. Submitting an answer separately right after the question - as many do, btw -, could be delaye by bad internet connection, like my mobile internet. What you mention is not the only reasonable option. I do not see much to debate there.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The first thing to remember is that the self answered question feature is there for a reason.

The second thing to remember is to judge both the question and the answer on their merits, not their apparent simplicity. Treat them like any other question/answer combo.

If either the question or answer is well written or researched and shows work, then up vote it. If they're terrible then down vote and/or vote to close. If they're okay or you can't make up your mind then don't worry about it, just ignore it. Don't obsess over the question - if you can't decide then let the rest of the community do it for you.

As for the simplicity - what is basic for you is not necessarily basic for someone else. Nor should we hate on a question because it's somehow answered in some doco somewhere. The goal of Stack Exchange is to collect quality information - there is no stipulation that it has to be of a specific minimum difficulty (not that we allow dumbass questions, but you get my meaning, right?).

Comment: I think I follow, it doesn't matter how "simple" the solution/problem is, if it's sufficiently obscured then it's still justified?

Comment: @CyanAngel There's a difference between "simple" (which can still be puzzling or obscure for beginners) and dumbass rep-farming questions (which can also be simple). You can spot the difference between the two - one should live, the other should be blown (voted) to obscurity. If you can't decide which it is then leave it, don't sweat it.

Comment: I get you, I'm guessing that over time I'll get better at spotting the difference, thanks for your help and advice

Comment: My only reservation about the question in question is that it is too specific and narrowly-applicable to be of use to others in the future.

Comment: I've come across a few "How do I do X" questions that should have been closed as being too broad, especially since they didn't provide any code.  In these kinds of situations, it's obvious to me that the OP was just doing it to troll for some free rep.  These are still ok?  Since the OP answered it, closing it only prevents more trash answers.