# advice to new user about basic/self-answered question?

Tags: discussion, new-users, self-answer

A new user asked this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37396676/fit-linear-regression-in-r , which seems (1) very basic and (2) not framed as a typical SO "how do I solve this problem?" question, but rather as "is my solution to this problem correct?" I understand that the latter is deprecated on SO (doesn't seem quite appropriate for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) though ...)

However, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the user's approach; they are asking a concrete question ("how do I run a linear regression?") with a concrete example. I suggested in comments that they might want to ask this question as "how do I run a linear regression?" and self-answer it, but I'm afraid they'll get downvoted into oblivion for asking too basic a question (there doesn't seem to be something this basic in the [r] tag already: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[r]+how+do+I+run+a+linear+regression ).

What are useful ways/the best way to encourage this user and guide them in the SO way? Should I just tell them nicely that this question is inappropriate for SO and they should find another basic R/statistics forum in which to ask (but come back to SO when they have more appropriate questions), or is there a way they can adjust their question to be good for SO?

The answers to [Self-answered questions about basic concepts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260781/self-answered-questions-about-basic-concepts) suggest that this question would be fine if it were asked as "how do I do linear regression?", but as I suggested above I'm afraid the user will get flamed for asking it ... any suggestions for ways to head that off?

**update**: user has now self-deleted, but I'm still curious

[image]

Comment: I don't see an SO question there as it sits.  The OP needs to test his own code to see if it works.  If it doesn't, he could describe the problem in a question.